# Sum total items in multiple shopping carts using Laravel collection methods

Tags: php, laravel, aggregate, laravel-collection

Say I have a shopping cart with relationship:

```
public function items()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'cart_item', 'cart_id', 'item_id')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

Say I have multiple `$carts` with each `$cart->items` and I want to generate a list of all items in this cart with summation on `pivot.quantity`.

e.g:

```
[
  {'item': Apple, 'pivot.quantity': 2},
  {'item': Orange, 'pivot.quantity': 1},
]

[
  {'item': Apple, 'pivot.quantity': 4},
  {'item': Banana, 'pivot.quantity': 1},
]
```

Will produce

```
[
  {'item': Apple, 'pivot.quantity': 6},
  {'item': Banana, 'pivot.quantity': 1},
  {'item': Orange, 'pivot.quantity': 1},
]
```

My thought would be first to iterate through all `$carts` to produce a list like this:

`[$cart[0]->items[0], $cart[0]->items[1], …, $cart[n]->items[n]]`

Is it possible to achieve something like this in one line?

Then summation would be a trivial `groupBy('item')` followed with appropriate `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
 $carts = [
   // this is your array;
 ];    

 $newCart = collect($carts)->flatten(1)->groupBy("item")->map(function($q){
    $item = $q->first()['item'];

    $quantity = $q->reduce(function($carry, $item){
        // Use this, as your quantity is not an object 
        // of pivot 
        return $carry + $item['pivot.quantity'];
        // use this if quantity is an object of pivot
        return $carry + $item['pivot']['quantity'];
    });

    return compact("item","quantity");
})->values();
```

Hope it helps.